# Making infinite scrolling without jQuery in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I want to make an infinite scroll from the data taken from the ng-repeat and to load the data when scroll has reached bottom in Angular JS using directive without the help of jQuery and ng-infinite-scroll.

Comment: Why don't you use ngInfinite i.e. ng-infinite-scroll.js

Answer (score 2):

I am using ngInfiniteScroll directive, that you can use to implement infinite scrolling in your AngularJS applications.

Simply declare which function to call when the user gets close to the bottom of the content with the directive and the module will take care of the rest. Of course, you can specify several options to ensure that the behavior is just what you're looking for.

You will find this same technique on the Facebook timeline or on Pinterest's homepage. You will get it from here:
[ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

Also you can see the basic demo here:
[ngInfiniteScroll basic demo](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html)

Comment: Is this answer different from mine?

Comment: Chill bro, its the same answer. Coincidentally we both were writing together at the same time.

Comment: ngInfiniteScroll uses jquery though, and the question was whether it's possible without jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to use virtual repeat mechanism of material angular, if you are using material with angular js, just follow this `:https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat`

Comment: can it be done using the window object in angular js

Comment: No in case of this your specific requirement , it will not prove better useful.

Answer (score 0):

Creating without jquery will be difficult for you but you can always check the implementation of **ngInfiniteScroll** and then make it in pure JS by yourself.

Otherwise use **ngInfiniteScroll** with jquery

I am using in one my application, it works like a charm

You will need following scripts for the same :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/angular.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js'></script>
```

For more [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

Demos of same : [demo_async](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html) and [demo_basic](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html)

Comment: ngInfiniteScroll uses jquery though, and the question was whether it's possible without jquery